# .mount a folder from the salt:// share onto a minion?

Tags: saltstack, sophos

I'm trying to write a state that will mount the folder currently in the "salt://" directory with the sophos installer, run the installer.sh, then unmount it. I'm hoping to avoid copying the whole folder or setting up a file share just for this purpose, but i'm not sure if that's possible. Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

`salt://` is not really share (at least not normally), it's part salt's internal file system. I would not recommend mounting parts of the real file system mapped from salt. You are better off having a repository system (which could include a shared ro filesystem), separate from salt, to hold your distribution files if they're too big to serve via salt directly.